# How to get file and read it from internet with Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a changelog that gets updated at runtime, now, I would like to download the changelog from my website, and then display it.
How would I do this?

By the way, I just want to read the file (something like when browsers ask you `do you want to save or run this file?`, not save it.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Look into jsoup its a headless browser that can scrape the html of your webpage

Comment: @Matt I know I can use selenium too. But this time I would like to do this with basic Java (I don't want to use any other things because though in this scale is still efficient, it's not the best most efficient way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the input stream from the URI in Java as follows. Replace `InputStreamReader` with other implementations as per your need. Once you have the reader, you should be able to read the data from the stream.

```
InputStream stream = new URI('http://path-to-file').toURL().openStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String content = "";
while((content = r.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(content); // you can put custom logic here.
}
```

Comment: This seems to work(?), but if i write `r.toString()` this is the output `java.io.InputStreamReader@aa549e5 
`

Comment: Try using `BufferedReader`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If you are open to using Apache commons, you could also try using `IOUtils.toString(stream)` to simplify.

Comment: @A.Dato , is the answer acceptable to you?